# Problems after adding starred sections headings in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, titletoc, starred-version

My document has both starred and non-starred version of section, and I want to add both types to my table of contents. I am using titletoc and I tried to solve it as follows:

```
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\Large\bfseries}
{}{0em}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]
{\large\filcenter\bfseries}
{}{0em}{#1\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}

\titlecontents*{section}[0em]{\normalsize}{}{}{~\thecontentspage}
[, ][.\vspace{0.5em}]
```

This almost works as I want, apart from two problems:

1. When I use a \section* in my document, I get the following warning:

> Package hyperref Warning: The anchor of a bookmark and its parent's must not
>   (hyperref)                be the same. Added a new anchor on input line 160.

2. Sometimes in the generated table of contents, there is a space between the end of the section heading and the comma separating it from the next heading, like this:

> PART 1: A PART HEADING 1
>
> A section heading 1, A starred section heading 1 , another section heading 1.

I tried changing the end of my titlecontents definition to:

```
[\unskip, ][.\vspace{0.5em}]
```

which did get rid of some of the undesired spaces, but not all of them. I have no idea what is causing the extra space to be generated. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, with a lot of trial and error I finally figured out a solution.

To get rid of the hyperref warning : use \phantomsection :

```
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}[block]                                             
% how to handle \section*
{\large\filcenter\bfseries}
{}{0em}{#1\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
```

To get rid of the space that appears before the comma separator when section* entries appear in the TOC :

Even though I am not displaying subsection or lower in the TOC:

```
\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
```

it is still necessary to define a \titlecontents line for subsection and subsubsection. Then the mysterious spaces vanish.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create your own sectioning commands:

```
\newcommand{\nonumsection}[1]{\section*{#1}%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#1}}
```

You need to create one command for nonum-chapter, -subsection, etc. That's how I always do it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried it but it didn't solve either of the issues.